# PHP Check if page contains

Tags: php

I'm looking for a quick code/function that will detect if a page contains a certain thing.

It's for a new project I'm working on.

Basically, the user will paste a simple javascript code into their pages, but I need to make sure they do.

I need a code that will scan through a specific webpage url and find the code I provided.

Thanks!

Comment: How, I'm fairly new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Go back through previous questions you've asked, and accept the best answer for each one - it's the big green tick to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to scan through a webpage, not an URL! You get to the webpage through an URL. :)

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents("http://some.site/page.html");
$search   = <<<EOF
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('They must have this!');
</script>
EOF;

if (strpos($contents, $search) === FALSE) {
    echo "Naughty webpage!";
}
?>
```

Note, though, that programmatically skimming pages like this is generally considered bad form.

Comment: Won't whitespace throw this off?

Comment: @jnpcl: How so? If you're looking at whitespace at the end of the `$search = <<<EOF` line, or the newline at the end of the `</script>` line, then [no](http://codepad.org/lyzkAs8O).

Comment: @Tomalak: A few spaces before `alert()` or the closing `</script>` tag?

Comment: This is easily thrown of by html indentation or CRLF variations. Better to strip all whitespace from the $subject and $search text beforehand.

Comment: @jnpcl: The OP wanted to search for some text on a webpage. If there are spaces on the webpage that aren't in the search string then, sure, it'll fail. It's not a match. If the requirements are more complex than stated and some dynamic searching needs to be performed, then that's a different question entirely.

Comment: Works perfect for me. Thanks bud !

Answer (score 2):

You can get the contents of a URL as a string, and search the contents for that code:

```
<?php
function check_url($url) {
    $page = file_get_contents($url);
    $code = '<script src="http://example.com/test.js"></script>';
    if (strpos($page, $code) === FALSE) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

You may want to swap that simple `strpos` out for a regular expression, but this will do the trick.

Comment: This fails when the script is found at the start of the webpage. And no ew regex! And no script MIME type given here :(

Comment: If the string is found at the start of the page, then the position is `int(0)`. It's a valid position, but your conditional treats it as a failure case. Use `===` to strictly compare against the `FALSE` that `strpos` returns on failure.

Comment: Ah yes, not got my head screwed on today! Thanks, have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the 2 things:

1) [get the content of remote url](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15706743/2220042)

2) check if the content contains your string:

```
if ( stristr($content, 'your_desired_string') )
{
    echo ' Yes, found';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

there are great libraries for crawling websites like [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) but in your case it seems to be an overkill to use it. If you want to use the cURL library I recommend the [Snoopy](http://snoopy.sourceforge.net/)-class to you which is very simple to use.

Felix

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, and _php_ has `file_get_contents` built-in so no need for a library.