# get url content PHP

Tags: php, url, curl, file-get-contents

I wanna put the content of a URL in a string and the process it. However, I have a problem.

I get this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.findchips.com/avail?part=74ls244) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached,
```

I have heard this comes due to page protection and headers, cookies and stuff.
How can I override it?

I also have tried alternatives such as fread along with fopen but I guess I just don't know how to do this.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: To everyone who answered: None of it is a solution to fixing redirection loops. Or showing how to configure PHP correctly to raise the limit.

Answer (score 35):

original answer moved to [this  topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15708596/2377343)                                 .

Comment: Why curl is "Better way"? Are these reasons absolute or relative-to requirements? thanks :)

Comment: excuse me: There are reasons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844299/using-file-get-contents-or-curl
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064980/php-curl-vs-file-get-contents

Comment: There's conflicting information in those above links: "FWIW there's little difference with regards to speed. I've just finished fetching 5,000 URLs and saving their HTML to files (about 200k per file). I did half with curl and half with file_get_contents as an experiment and there was no discernible difference." and follow-on comment "I benchmarked the two on 5.3 and 5.4, and cURL still is considerably faster than file_get_contents, especially for multiple calls on the same request." vs "A few years ago I benchmarked the two and CURL was faster."...

Comment: You sir have saved me today, thank you for thy good deed !

Comment: @tazo todua  How can I get the html text, when I run this example it display the whole website view.

Answer (score 17):

Use [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php),

Check if you have it via `phpinfo();`

And for the code:

```
function getHtml($url, $post = null) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    if(!empty($post)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    } 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: What is this line for?  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

Comment: Nope, that doesn't do it

Answer (score 3):

Try using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead. cURL implements a cookie jar, while file_get_contents doesn't.

Comment: could you give me an example of how i get the content of a url with cURL? I have a problem with the example of php.net