# How to grab specifc data from another website with PHP's fgetcsv and fopen

Tags: php, html, web-crawler, fopen

I'd like to be able to grab data such as list of articles from yahoo finance. At the moment I have a local hosted webpage that searched yahoo finance for **stock symbols (E.g Nok)**, It then returns the opening price, current price, and how far up or down the price has gone.

What I'd like to do is actually grab related links that yahoo has on the page - These links have articles related to the share price...E.g `https://au.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=nok&ql=1` Scroll down to headlines, I'd like to grab those links.

At the moment I'm working off a book (PHP Advanced for the world wide web, I know it's old but I found it laying around yesterday and it's quite interesting :) ) In the book it says 'It's important when accessing web pages to know exactly where the data is' - I would think by now there would be a way around this...Maybe the ability to search for links that have a particular keyword in it or something like that!

I'm wondering if theres a special trick I can use to grab particular bits of data on a webpage?? Like crawlers, they are able to grab links that are related to something. 
It would be great to know how to do this, then i'd be able to apply it to other subjects in the future.

Ill add my code that I have at the moment. This is purely for practise as I'm learning PHP in my course :)

```
##getquote.php
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3// DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xhtml1-20000126/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Get Stock Quotes</title>
        <link href='css/style.css' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <h1>Stock Reader</h1>
        <body>
    <?php

    //Read[1] = current price
    //read[5] = opening price
    //read[4] = down or up whatever percent from opening according to current price


    //Step one    
    //Begin the PHP section my checking if the form has been submitted
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            //Step two
            //Check if a stock symbol was entered.
            if(isset($_POST['symbol'])){

            //Define the url to be opened
            $url = 'http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=' . $_POST['symbol'] . '&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv';

                //Open the url, if can't SHUTDOWN script and write msg
            $fp = fopen($url, 'r') or die('Cannot Access YAHOO!.');
        //This will get the first 30 characters from the file located in $fp
            $read = fgetcsv ($fp, 30);
                //Close the file processsing.
                fclose($fp);
                include("php/displayDetails.php");

            }

            else{
                echo "<div style='color:red'>Please enter a SYMBOL before submitting the form</div>";
            }

        }
    ?>
            <form action='getquote.php' method='post'>
                <p>Symbol: </p><input type='text' name='symbol'>
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value='Fetch Quote' name="submit">

            </form>
            <br />
            <br />

##displayDetails.php

    <div class='display-contents'>
    <?php
                echo "<div>Todays date: " . $read[2] . "</div>";
                //Current price
                echo "<div>The current value for " . $_POST["symbol"] . " is <strong>$ " . $read[1] . "</strong></div>";
                //Opening Price
                echo "<div>The opening value for " . $_POST["symbol"] . " is <strong>$ " . $read[5] . "</strong></div>";

                if($read[1] < $read[5])
                {
                //Down or Up depending on opening.
                echo "<div>" .strtoupper($_POST['symbol']) ."<span style='color:red'> <em>IS DOWN</em> </span><strong>$" . $read[4] . "</strong></div>";
                }
                else{
                     echo "<div>" . strtoupper($_POST['symbol']) ."<span style='color:green'> <em>IS UP</em> </span><strong>$" . $read[4] . "</strong></div>";

        }
```

### added code to displayDetails.php

```
function getLinks(){
    $siteContent = file_get_contents($url);
$div = explode('class="yfi_headlines">',$siteContent); 
    // every thing inside is a content you want

    $innerContent = explode('<div class="ft">',$div)[0]; //now you have inner content of your div;

$list  = explode("<ul>",$innerConent)[1];
$list  = explode("</ul>",$list)[0];

    echo $list;
}

        ?>
        </div>
```

I just the same code in - I didn't really know what I should do with it?!

Comment: Any site that allows you yo take their data provides an API

Answer (score 0):

Idk for `fgetcsv`  but with `file_get_contents` you can grab whole content of a page into a string variable.
Then you can search for links in string (do not use regex for html content search: [Link regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/2656311))

I briefly looked at yahoo's source code so you can do:
-yfi_headlines is a div class witch wrappes desired links

```
$siteContent = file_get_contents($url);
$div = explode('class="yfi_headlines">',$siteContent)[1]; // every thing inside is a content you want
```

-last class inside searched div is: ft

```
$innerContent = explode('<div class="ft">',$div)[0]; //now you have inner content of your div;
```

repeat for getting `<ul>` inner content

```
$list  = explode("<ul>",$innerConent)[1];
$list  = explode("</ul>",$list)[0];
```

now you have a list of links in format: `<li><a href="href">text</a></li>`

There are more efficient ways to parse web page like using DOMDocument:
[Example](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/html-xpath-query/)
For getting content of a page you can also look at this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15706743/2656311

[ADITIONALY] IF it is a large website: at the beggining of a function do: `ini_set("memory_limit","1024M")`; so you can store more data to your memory!

Comment: Thanks. Do you reckon you could make a code example? I've tried to put it together and get it to work but I can't.

Comment: I've added the code I put in...It's all the code you gave me. I didn't really know what and where to add it!