# How could I read a file from url display on ace editor

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, ace-editor

These days I am studying ajax and ace editor, I want to read a url file and display it on ace editor, I don't know how to get it when the url is https, do you have a good method?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.6/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" media="all"/>
<style>
#code1,#code2{
 height:800px;
 font-size:14px;
 border-bottom:2px solid #999;
}
ul.app_cat_ul{
 padding:0px;
 list-style:none;
 overflow:hidden;
}
ul.app_cat_ul li a:hover{
 background-color:#EEE;
}
/* nav */
ul.nav_ul{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 list-style:none;
 overflow:hidden;
}
ul.nav_ul li{
 float:left;
 margin-right:3px;
}
ul.nav_ul li a{
 padding:12px;
 display:block;
 color:#555;
 background-color:#FFF;
 border:1px solid #EEE;
}
ul.nav_ul li a:hover{
 background-color:#EEE;
}
ul.ul_buttons li a{
 margin:5px 0px;
 color:#555;
 background-color:#FFF;
 border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
             <h1>ACE ajax test</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="well well-sm">
                 <form class="form-inline text-left">
                    <fieldset>
                    
                    <div class="form-group buttons_div">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                       <ul class="nav_ul ul_buttons">
                         <li><a id="load_url" href="#">Load&nbsp;Url</a></li>
                            <li><a id="browse" href="#">Browse</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <input style="display:none;" id="file" name="file" class="btn btn-default" type="file">
                    </fieldset>
                    </form>
                 <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 div_code1">
                         <div class="h_text">Enter here:</div>
                            <div id="code1"></div>
                         <div id="code2" style="display:none"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="url_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Enter Url</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                           <input id="url" name="url" type="text" placeholder="Enter full url" class="form-control input-md">
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                           <button data-dismiss="modal" id="load" name="load" class="btn btn-success">Load</button>
                            <button data-dismiss="modal" id="cancel" name="cancel" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
             <div class="well well-sm data_tb text-left" style="overflow:auto;display:none;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zclip/1.1.2/jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.3/ace.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.3/ext-language_tools.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 
 ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
 var editorAce1 = ace.edit("code1");
 editorAce1.focus();
 editorAce1.setOptions({
  enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
  enableSnippets: true,
  enableLiveAutocompletion: true
 });
    editorAce1.setTheme("ace/theme/chrome");
    editorAce1.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/plain_text");
 
 var editorAce2 = ace.edit("code2");
 editorAce2.setOptions({
  enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
  enableSnippets: true,
  enableLiveAutocompletion: true
 });
    editorAce2.setTheme("ace/theme/chrome");
    editorAce2.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
 editorAce2.getSession().setUseWorker(false);
 
 
 $("#load_url").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
  $("#url_modal").modal({backdrop : false});
    });
 
 $("#load").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
  url = $.trim($("#url").val());
  if(url != "")
  {
   editorAce1.getSession().setUseWorker(false);
   editorAce1.setValue("Please wait while loading file from url.");
   $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url  : "/get_data.php",
    dataType: "text",
    data : {"url" : url},
    success : function(data)
    {
     if(data == "file_not_found")
     {
      editorAce1.setValue("Unable to load file from url!");
     }else
     {
      editorAce1.getSession().setUseWorker(true);
      editorAce1.setValue(data);
     }
    },
    error  : function()
    {
     editorAce1.setValue("Unable to load file from url!");
    }
   });
  }
    });
 
 $("#browse").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
  $("#file").click();
    });
 
 function read_file(e)
 {
  f = e.target.files[0];
  if(f)
  {
   r = new FileReader();
   r.onload = function(e)
   {
    var contents = e.target.result;
    var file_name = f.name;
    editorAce1.getSession().setUseWorker(true);
    editorAce1.setValue(contents);
   }
   r.readAsText(f);
  }
  else
  {
   editorAce1.getSession().setUseWorker(false);
   editorAce1.setValue("Unable to load file!");
  }
 }
 
 $("#file").change(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
  read_file(e);
    });
 
 
 
 themelist = ace.require("ace/ext/themelist");
 theme = "";
 $(themelist.themes).each(function(key, value) {
  theme += '<option value="' + value.name + '">' + value.caption + '</option>';
    });
 $("#themes").append(theme);
 
 $("#themes").val("chrome");
 $("#font_size").val("14");
 
 $("#themes,#font_size").change(function(e) {
        setTheme();
  editorAce1.focus();
    });
});


 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[The userface pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18Xyt.png)
[Core code pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaWiR.png)
Most of codes have worked well. Could you help me write the get_data.php file for me, let the page work. Thanks.

Comment: your question is not really related to ace editor, and would be more likely to be answered if you leave only the part about get_data.php, in which case it would be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363022/get-url-content-php